# Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder and Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, report

Is it possible to process Google Analytics data in MS SQL Server Report Builder?

And if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GoogleAnalyticsDataProcessingExtension](https://github.com/farzadpanahi/GoogleAnalyticsDataProcessingExtension) to add Google Analytics as a Data Source to your report.

Disclaimer: I wrote it :>